# Difference between "After all, ...?" and "... anyway?"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am unable to differentiate between the meaning conveyed by the following two sentences:

> 1. After all, what is so hard about Quantum Field Theory?
> 2. What is so hard about Quantum Field Theory anyway?

I want to confirm whether they do convey the same meaning or there is some difference between the meaning conveyed by the two. Thanks!

Comment: The two expressions are used in different ways and "literally" mean different things, but in this "figurative" use there really is no difference.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment. And it would further be equivalent to "What is so hard about it after all?". Right?

Comment: I think the placement of "after all" is a question of personal style, nothing more.  Sometimes it *sounds* better before, sometimes after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sentence would likely come after:

> **I built a quantum computer in my spare time.** *After all, what is so hard about Quantum Field Theory?*

Meaning the speaker fully understands the subject but not why others do not
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/after_all

To me the place of the "after all" is interchangeable - I do prefer the sentence above to this one:

> **I built a quantum computer in my spare time.** *What is so hard about Quantum Field Theory after all?*

---

The second comes after a sentence like

> **All the nerds in my uni sweat day and night over their Quantum thesis'.** *What is so hard about Quantum Field Theory anyway?*

Meaning the speaker does NOT understand Quantum field theory but doubts it can be hard or feels that his subject is much harder (Think Sidney Sheldon)

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anyway (examples 1.1)

If you use anyway before the sentence, you are changing subject:

> **So I finally finished and went to watch TV.** *Anyway, what is so hard about Quantum Field Theory?*

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your answer. Can you comment whether "What is so hard about Quantum Field Theory after all?" will be used in a situation similar to "What is so hard about QFT anyway?" or "After all, what is so hard about QFT?"?

Comment: I would think using after all before or after the sentence is interchangeable. It just sounds more idiomatic to my ears if it is before the sentence

Comment: I gave other examples of what happens if you move _Anyway_ to the front of the sentence etc